# Java Jsoup scraping website data trouble

Tags: java, jsoup

Completely new to Java and Jsoup. I am trying to create a simple program that scrapes the web and gives me data on the stock market in Java. I would like to start out with dow jones stocks and have it print out the 52 week range data. It goes to http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?ltr=1 and looks at the lower lefthand table (that starts with previous close) and goes down to the 5th index and gets the text value from there. I get the error:

Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query 'table.W(100%)': unexpected token at '(100%)'

Which means somewhere in there I got the table class wrong? How do I make this code work?

I started with apple (AAPL) stocks frist and came up with this in Jsoup:

---

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Scraper {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?ltr=1").get();

    Elements table = doc.select("table.W(100%)");
    Element row = table.select("tr").get(5);

    final String number = row.select("td").text();
    System.out.println(number);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try first grabbing all the table elements and then selecting the one with that class:

```
Elements tables = doc.select("table");
Element table = null;

for(Element tableElement : tables){
    if(tableElement.hasClass("W(100%)")){
        table = tableElement;
    }
}
```

The Html parser can't handle and parse elements with () on them, so that throws an error. This is a simple workaround to avoid that issue.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Now I am just getting some wierd issues with Nullpointerexception when I do Element row = table.select("tr"); That should get all the rows right?

Comment: Yes, that should get all the table rows.. however, it would return Elements not Element. Here is a link to the API to see what all the methods are/return: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/